# When was the first Harry Potter book written

Tags: harry-potter

Is it true that the first Harry Potter book was written in the same year that the Hogwarts battle ended in and what is the famous saying for J.K Rowling about this?
 I have heard about this but not clearly and want to read a more specific quote.

Comment: I haven't the foggiest what you're trying to ask.

Comment: Are you referring to JK Rowling's [apology for killing off Snape](https://www.theverge.com/platform/amp/tldr/2017/5/2/15519164/jk-rowling-hogwarts-battle-snape-death-apology-twitter) and others?

Comment: @b_jonas - I've rolled back the title edit. It's not in the least bit clear that that's what OP actually meant and unless I've missed something, they haven't communicated to clarify the meaning

Comment: @b_jonas I like the spirit of your edit, but it seems like you're trying to edit the question to fit your answer.

Answer (score 4):

Not quite.

[The Battle of Hogwarts took place on May 2, 1998.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/64920/4918)  The first book, *Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone* was published some in year 1997.

I don't know about any famous saying on this.